# android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView

Tags: android, android-tablayout, tabitem

Here is the activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.issaayoub.materialtest.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="4dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:icon="@drawable/an"
                    android:text="@string/bird1" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout">

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:name="com.issaayoub.materialtest.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Whenever I added the current TabItem inside the TabLayout I got the following error:

> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.ImageView

When opening the details of the rendering problem I got the follows:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.update(TabLayout.java:1675)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.setTab(TabLayout.java:1627)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:927)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.newTab(TabLayout.java:562)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTabFromItemView(TabLayout.java:481)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addViewInternal(TabLayout.java:970)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addView(TabLayout.java:960)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:862)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$53(RenderTask.java:659)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Could someone please highlight out what is the problem with the TabItem.

*Removing the TabItem will remove all this error. Finally, please note that the application is running normally without any error on the phone/emulator.*

Thanks for help!!

Comment: kindly post your `MainActivity` code

Comment: Can u post your `MainActivity.class` code

Comment: The MainActivity.class has no effect since what I used to do is: add the TabItem, then the error appear, then remove the TabItem, then error is removed. Hence, this is has nothing to do with the Java code inside MainActivity class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing worked out. I restarted Android Studio and the error was removed.
Please note that we can add both a text and an icon. 
Here is a picture for of layout of the application:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:text="@string/tab_text"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

looking at the code given at [Android Devp website](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html), I think only text or icon can be given here, not both.

Try it out.

Comment: please note that you can add both an icon and a text to the ItemTab

Comment: I have used a custom tab item for adding images and text, did not know it was possible directly. Thanks for that